# separated foreground and background or change the value of background image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How should I change the background image color to black or change the RGB values become black color background. I want to take the original leaf image only.

Leaf image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the background color to black you'll need the following:

1. calculate the background mask by using a threshold
   The threshold can be either find automatically, by using the function graythresh, or manually, by looking at the image histogram.
2. perform thresholding by using the value from stage 1 in order to find the foreground mask. Also, pick the largest connected component and perform noise cleaning (imclose operation).
3. calculate the BG from the FG, and zero out the corresponding locations in the original input image.

Code example:

```
I = imread('YaEwk.jpg');

%converts to hsv colorspace, and takes the 3rd dimension. normlizes it.
im = rgb2hsv(I);
im = mat2gray(im(:,:,3));

%determines a threshold to distinguish between the leaf and its surroundings.
T = graythresh(im); 

%defines FG as all the values below the threshold
%Also, keeps just the biggest connected component and perform noise
%reduction.
FG = im < T;
FG = bwareafilt(FG,1);
FG = imclose(FG,strel('disk',2));

%defines the background as the opposite of the foreground
BG = ~FG;
I(repmat(BG,1,1,3)) = 0;

%smooth the output
I(:,:,1) = medfilt2(I(:,:,1));
I(:,:,2) = medfilt2(I(:,:,2));
I(:,:,3) = medfilt2(I(:,:,3));
```

Result:

[image: output image]

Comment: thanks a lot for yours respon drorco, the result's i wanted. 
but when i'm using bwareafilt like yours code, why bwareafilt is not undefined in my matlab. I'm using matlab 7.7.0 (R2008b).

Comment: Hi Edo, does the function bwconncomp available in your matlab version?

Comment: Hi Drorco. i dont know how to check list of function in my matlab. but i try to open with help in my matlab. it so many list, im confuse. hehehe.
but when i try to little modify yours code, that's success. like yours result.
here the code:
f = imread('1.jpg');
im = rgb2hsv(f);
im = mat2gray(im(:,:,3));
T = graythresh(im);
FG = im < T;
FG = imclose(FG,strel('disk',2));
figure,imshow(FG);
BG = ~FG;
f(repmat(BG,1,3)) = 0;
figure,imshow(f);

the difference is i'm not using bwareafilt and in the line repmat function.
there will be a significant risk in the future ??

Comment: It's sounds ok. If you want to be more confident with the current solution -my advice to you is to try it on more input images and see if the results are satisfying. If you have anymore questions - let me know. good luck!

Comment: Yes, i'll try to another leaf for data set from internet. i want use this image for another proses in matlab like a FFT2 and get the power spectrum. Thanks a lot for your help Mr Drorco. Hope GOD bless you anywhere. I come from Indonesia, nice to see you  :).

Comment: Hii, mr Drorco,
how are you,,??
Can I ask something again..???

how to get average power spectrum from the image..??
do you have a little examples from paper or reference about that..??

i need basic algorithms to learn how to calculate average power spectrum and implementation with matlab??
I upgrade my matlab to R2015a right now..
hehehe

thank you.. :)

Comment: @edo hi edo :) I suggest posting a new question about this issue , since it is a different subject from this one. good luck!